# What are the CRs for diseases used in traps, and how are they calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, traps, cr-calculation, disease

Are there guidelines for determining the CR of diseases when they're part of traps? I'm actually interested specifically in [Tetanus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/diseases/diseases-paizo-inc/tetanus/), but the lack of a clear answer of which I'm aware leads to me to ask the question more generally.

We have the CRs of several poisons in the trap rules, and I suppose we could work backward from calculable values of published traps with disease components, such as the [infected punji pit trap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps/infected-punji-pit-trap-cr-4/). But are there guidelines anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Disease is something that, in my experience, is difficult to assign a fair CR. Assuming you have someone capable of casting Cure Disease, Standard diseases stop being a challenge past level 5, and even before then they are slow acting enough that they are not dangerous in a single encounter, but instead over the course of an entire adventure.

What I have found works the best is to treat the disease as a +1 if the trap can only target a single character, or +2 CR in a trap that can target multiple characters so long as this does not push the trap over CR 6 for standard diseases.

Diseases that do not allow for cures (even through Remove Disease) or that increase the number of required castings can push it further, depending on how much it increases difficulty, but without good (plot) reason I would not recommend using special diseases like those in a trap (as it can easily lead to un-fun unless your group is into that).